# Synchronized ArrayList Concurrent Writing

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, arraylist

everyone. To Test a ArrayList returned by the Collections.synchronizedList() method, I defined a static class as below.

```
static class ListWriter implements Runnable { 
    private List<Integer> list; 

    public ListWriter(List<Integer> list) { 
        this.list = list; 
    } 

    public void run() {  // I didn't use synchronized(list) {} block here.
        try { 
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
                list.add(i); 
                Thread.sleep(10); 
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

and a test method as below

```
private static void test1() throws Exception {
    List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ListWriter(list)); 
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ListWriter(list));

    t1.start(); 
    t2.start(); 
    t1.join(); 
    t2.join(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) { 
        System.out.println(list.get(i)); 
    } 
}
```

The result is usually this:
  0
  0
  1
  1
  2
  2
  3
  3
  4
  4
  5
  5
  6
  6
  7
  7
  8
  8
  9
  9
  10
  10
  11
  11
  12
  12
  13
  13
  14
  14
  15
  15
  16
  16
  17
  17
  18
  18
  19
  19

But sometimes it will be like this:

0
  0
  1
  1
  2
  3
  2
  3
  4
  5
  4
  5
  6
  7
  6
  8
  7
  9
  8
  10
  9
  11
  10
  12
  11
  13
  12
  14
  13
  15
  14
  15
  16
  17
  16
  17
  18
  19
  18
  19

Does these results indicates the process is thread-safe?
The point is that I didn't use a synchronized block in the writing thread which is explicitly required for iterating over the synchronized ArrayList returned by Collection.synchronizedList() method. So do you think the process is thread-safe or do I need to use synchronized block anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is non-deterministic - it depends on the scheduling behaviour of the underlying operating system.
The fact that sometime you get a certain sequence is just a coincidence.
Your list is synchronised at creation by the `Collections.synchronizedList` so you don't need any additional synchronisation.

A rough test of the thread-safeness of your list would be to validate that the number of elements contained in the list equals 40 after both threads are done.

As you noted, for concurrent reading you will need to synchronize on the returned list as stated in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

Answer (score 0):

The `add` method is synchronized so you don't need to add any extra sychronization to your code. The reason why the numbers can be out of order is that the 2 threads are halted with `Thread.sleep()` which is not very precise, so it is possible that one thread overtabkes the other slightly, producing the second output.

If you remove the `Thread.sleep()` you would get even more variations of the output.

Answer (score 0):

`list` is synchronized so you don't need to add any extra code.

Output may not be the same each time, because threads will be running randomly as they will get processor.

Check [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of threads is to run independent tasks.  When this is not the case, they have to co-ordinate their actions and this can be an overhead.

What might be surprising is that you can't guarantee either the order threads run, nor how long they sleep for. You could have one thread run to completion before the second one starts. You could have your program or machine crash and the thread(s) never finish.

> Does these results indicates the process is thread-safe?

This indicates the threads are running independently as they should.

> The point is that I didn't use a synchronized block in the writing thread which is explicitly required for iterating over the synchronized ArrayList returned by Collection.synchronizedList() method

This is not a problem because there is no threads modifying the list at this point.

> So do you think the process is thread-safe or do I need to use synchronized block anyway?

No. If you are expecting a consistent order, don't use threads. It will be simpler and faster and give the same result every time. ;)